# Compare Column Data in a document library and a list

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, cqwp, content-query-web-part

Any ideas on how I can retrieve a column data in another list and compare it to a document library column, using XSLT and content query Webpart ?

For example, I have a  custom list called `Categories`. I have created a lookup column based on this list, and added to a document library.

I want to compare if the value within the look up column matches the column in the `Categories` custom list. Any ideas ?

Comment: Cross-posted at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78453/compare-column-data-in-a-document-library-and-a-list - please don't ask the same question on more than one StackExchange site.

Comment: What about using http://spservices.codeplex.com/ or http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/ ? With JavaScript you could do this kind of thing...